# Unexpected Identifier with Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, identifier

I am new at JS and I am a bit unsure if I am using the switch statement correctly or if there is something else wrong. I keep getting an Unexpected Identifier error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? Thank you very much in advance.

```
function likes(names) {
    var outPut = "";

    switch(names){
        case (names.length === 1):
          outPut = names[0] = "likes this";
          break;
        case (names.length === 2):
          outPut = names[0] + "and" + names[1] + "like this";
          break;
        case (names.length === 3):
          outPut = names[0] + " , " + names[1] + " and " + names[2] + " like this";
          break;
        case (names.length >= 4):
          outPut = names[0] + names[1] + " and " names.length - 2 + "like this";
          break;
        default:
          outPut = "no one likes this";
    }
  return outPut;
}
```

Comment: That's not the normal way to do a switch. Why not `switch(names.length) { case 1:...` ?

Comment: You forgot a `+` between `" and "` and `names.length`

Comment: You were looking for `if`/`else if`/`else`, not a `switch` statement.

Comment: I wanted to try and learn how to use a switch statement and was unsure of what kind of expression the statement took. I understand that part now. Also, I didn't realize my typos so thank you for pointing them out and to everyone for the speedy assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in `names.length >= 4`

The cleanest way of doing this is in a `if else` block.

```
var output = "no one likes this";

if (names.length === 1) {
  outPut = names[0] = "likes this";
} else if (names.length === 2) {
  outPut = names[0] + "and" + names[1] + "like this";
} else(names.length === 3):
  outPut = names[0] + " , " + names[1] + " and " + names[2] + " like this";
} else if (names.length >= 4):
  outPut = names[0] + names[1] + " and " + (names.length - 2) + "like this";
}
```

If you still want to use `switch`, you can modify your code slightly.

```
function likes(names) {
    var outPut = "";

    switch(names.length) {
        case 0:
            outPut = "no one likes this";
        case 1:
          outPut = names[0] = "likes this";
          break;
        case 2:
          outPut = names[0] + "and" + names[1] + "like this";
          break;
        case 3:
          outPut = names[0] + " , " + names[1] + " and " + names[2] + " like this";
          break;
        default:
          outPut = names[0] + names[1] + " and " +  (names.length - 2) + " like this";
    }
  return outPut;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper way to do it with `switch`:

```js
function likes(names) {
  var outPut = "";

  switch (names.length) {
    case 0:
      outPut = "no one likes this";
      break;
    case 1:
      outPut = names[0] + " likes this";
      break;
    case 2:
      outPut = names[0] + " and " + names[1] + " like this";
      break;
    case 3:
      outPut = names[0] + ", " + names[1] + " and " + names[2] + " like this";
      break;
    default:
      outPut = names[0] + ", " + names[1] + " and " + names[names.length - 2] + " like this";
      break;
  }
  return outPut;
}

console.log(likes(["Alice", "Bob", "Caesar"]));
```

It won't show all names for longer arrays though.

Answer (score 0):

```
outPut = names[0] + names[1] + " and " names.length - 2 + "like this";
```

It looks like you forgot a "+" between " and " and names.length.

```
outPut = names[0] = "likes this";
```

Also I think the second "=" should be a plus.